# Align input field with label vertically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap3. What is the correct way to align my right blue text (name) with input field below it?

```
<form id="myform" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-static">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9 form-control-static">
          <p class="text-primary">Samir Nasri</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-3 form-control-static">Title<span class="mandatory"> *</span></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="" placeholder="Title">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Check your class form-control-static, you have it on blue label, but its missing in input parent. Or may be your input have some margin-left

Comment: what do you mean by input parent?

Comment: Adding form-control-static to input parent does make it align. It's solved now. Thanks